# Slow fetch from GitHub

Tags: github

I notice this step takes about 10 seconds in a Jenkins step. Any idea how to troubleshoot this? We are using GitHub Enterprise inside the company.

```
> D:\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress http://github.sample.com/Trade-Efficiencies-CRD/OTPP.CRD.Customization.CRDBulkUploadAddIn.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Is it slow on the commandline too? Are you sure about `core.askpass=true` (see `core.askPass` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))?

Comment: There is no delay when run the above command from the CMD. We are using Jenkins credentials so this command is generated by Jenkins.

Comment: For the guy gives a "-1" to this question, can I ask why? Is this question too easy for you? Can you share a light please?

Comment: (It wasn't me that downvoted btw). I can only think of a few possibilities: there's an attempt to read the password from STDIN due to missing GIT_ASKPASS (since `true` does not produce output); [see here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials). Or, the repository is large, and it is fetched every time because it is deleted locally.

Comment: It's possible, but as I said that command is generated by Jenkins, don't know how to change that. This is probably the real question.

Answer (score 0):

Use jgit resolved the issue. Not sure if anybody else is experiencing the same issue, hope this can help.